# Remove Objects from a List based on their ID and collect Objects that have been removed to another List

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream

I want to remove from a list of `Employee` (`list1`) objects that are not present in another list of `Employee` (`list2`) by their `id` and add removed objects from `list1` into another list (`list3`) using Java 8.

**Example :**

```java
List<Employee> list1 = Stream.of(
                        new Employee("100","Boston","Massachusetts"),
                        new Employee("400","Atlanta","Georgia"),
                        new Employee("300","pleasanton","California"),
                        new Employee("200","Decatur","Texas"),
                        new Employee("500","Cumming","Atlanta"),
                        new Employee("98","sula","Maine"),
                        new Employee("156","Duluth","Ohio"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

From the above list need to remove `Employee` object based on `id` of below list.

```java
List<Employee> list2 = Stream.of(
                        new Employee("100","Boston","Massachusetts"),
                        new Employee("800","pleasanton","California"),
                        new Employee("400","Atlanta","Georgia"),
                        new Employee("10","Decatur","Texas"),
                        new Employee("500","Cumming","Atlanta"),
                        new Employee("50","sula","Maine"),
                        new Employee("156","Duluth","Ohio"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Expected Output :
**list1 and list3**

```java
       List<Employee> list1 = Stream.of(
                        new Employee("100","Boston","Massachusetts"),
                        new Employee("400","Atlanta","Georgia"),
                        new Employee("500","Cumming","Atlanta"),
                new Employee("156","Duluth","Ohio"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Employee> list3 = Stream.of(
                        new Employee("300","pleasanton","California"),
                        new Employee("200","Decatur","Texas"),
                        new Employee("98","sula","Maine")
                        )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Tried below way but not working as expected

```
        List<Employee> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
        if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list1) && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list2)){
            list2.stream().forEachOrdered( l2 -> {
                Optional<Employee> nonMatch = list1.stream().filter(l1 -> !l1.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(l2.getId())).findAny();
                if(nonMatch.isPresent()){
                    list3.add(nonMatch.get());
                    list1.removeIf(l1 -> l1.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(nonMatch.get().getId()));
                }
            });
        }

        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list3);
```

Comment: What have you tried doing? Please share your attempts and the community can provide feedback, suggestions, explanations for why it's not working correctly, etc.

Comment: @Kaan : updated in description

Comment: Why `retainAll` and `removeAll` methods of the list interface are not good enough?

Comment: @AlexSveshnikov, `retainAll` and `removeAll` utilize `equals`, whereas the OP stated, that comparison should happen based on ID only. Anyway, cloning `list1` and then using `retainAll` and `removeAll` might be the most elegant solution if run-time and memory foot-print are not an issue _and_ `equals` could be safely overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with your current code:

- Remember as the rule of thumb: every time you're finding yourself  changing something outside the stream using `forEach`, most likely something is going wrong (*have a look at the [*API documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects). You can invoke `forEach()` method on any type of collection without creating a stream, but keep in mind that using a multiline lambda inside `forEach()` doesn't bring you any advantage over a plain `for` loop.
- it's highly advisable to give your variable clear [*self-explanatory names*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code). Like `emplDeparmentX`, `empleOldDB`, etc. Names `list1` makes more difficult to reason about the code.

You can address this problem in the following steps (*time complexity of each step is **linear***):

- create a `Set` of `id` contained in the `list2` (*remainder: the time complexity of the contains check is* **O(1)**);
- generate the list of `Employee` (denoted as `nonCommonId` in the code) from the `list1` that have no common `id` with `Employee` contained in the `list2` by checking every `id` from the `list1` against the `Set` obtained at the previous step.
- Removing employees with different `id` from a list separately causes additional performance overhead because each removal has a linear time complexity. A better option will be to use `removeAll()`.
- apply `removeAll()` on the list `id` discard all the employee that are present in the list obtained at the previous step.

The overall time complexity **O(n + m)** (`n` and `m` - are numbers of elements in the `list1` and `list2`).

```
Set<String> idSet = list2.stream()
    .map(Employee::id)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            
List<Employee> nonCommonId = list1.stream()
    .filter(emp ->  !idSet.contains(emp.id()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            
list1.removeAll(new HashSet<>(nonCommonId)); // list `nonCommonId` is wrapped by the HashSet to improve performance, because `removeAll()` relies on the `contains()` checks
// diplaying results
System.out.println("List1:");
list1.forEach(System.out::println);
            
System.out.println("nonCommonId:");
nonCommonId.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
List1:
Employee[id=100, city=Boston, state=Massachusetts]
Employee[id=400, city=Atlanta, state=Georgia]
Employee[id=500, city=Cumming, state=Atlanta]
Employee[id=156, city=Duluth, state=Ohio]
nonCommonId:
Employee[id=300, city=pleasanton, state=California]
Employee[id=200, city=Decatur, state=Texas]
Employee[id=98, city=sula, state=Maine]
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/spb)

Answer (score 1):

Here come two possible solutions.

This one is short and concise, but does in fact not remove elements from `list1` but utilizes a partitioning collector to create the two lists. Think of the partitioning collector as kind of a two-way filter: if your predicate is fulfilled, collect to one list, if it's not, collect to the other list. The predicate in our case actually is "does list2 contain an employee with the same ID as the stream element from list1?". In order to lower the actual overhead, the code prepares a list of IDs from `list2` up-front.

```java
        final List<String> list2Ids = list2.stream()
                .map(Employee::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Map<Boolean, List<Employee>> partitioned = list1.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(e -> list2Ids.contains(e.getId())));

        list1 = partitioned.get(true);
        List<Employee> list3 = partitioned.get(false);
```

If you need to keep `list1` - e.g. for memory foot-print reasons - and really have to remove the elements from it, I'd say you will have to stick to the really old-fashioned iterator. The reason for that is that iterators allow you to iterate some collection *and* remove elements while doing so. The next sample does exactly this. Note, that I prepared a list of IDs of `list2` up-front again.

```java
        final List<String> list2Ids = list2.stream()
                .map(Employee::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        final List<Employee> list3 = new LinkedList<>();

        for (Iterator<Employee> iterator = list1.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Employee next = iterator.next();

            if (!list2Ids.contains(next.getId())) {
                list3.add(next);
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the distinct id list from list2

```
idList = list2.stream().map(Employee::getID).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Remove the employees having common id from list1 and get list3.

```
ArrayList<Employee> list3 =  list1.stream().filter(e->!idList .contains(e.getID())).collect(Collectors.toList());


list1 = list1.stream().filter(e->idList.contains(e.getID())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```